# How to select all rows before a threshold based on another column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

| Log Time | Session ID | Time Between Logs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12:00:01 | AAAAAA | 4 |
| 12:00:05 | AAAAAA | 4 |
| 12:00:09 | AAAAAA | 296 |
| 12:05:05 | AAAAAA | 10 |
| 12:05:15 | AAAAAA | NULL |
| 12:06:15 | BBBBBB | 16 |
| 12:06:31 | BBBBBB | 164 |
| 12:09:15 | BBBBBB | 10 |
| 12:09:25 | BBBBBB | NULL |
| 12:11:45 | CCCCCC | 5 |
| 12:11:50 | CCCCCC | 25 |
| 12:12:15 | CCCCCC | NULL |

I have a database which stores user logs. It consists of the

- **[Log Time]** - DATETIME datatype, I am excluding date here for simplicity, we can just assume all rows are in the same day
- **[Session ID]** - VARCHAR datatype, shows the session of the user in which he interacts with the app
- **[Time Between Logs]** - INT datatype, I have myself coded this to find the time between the consecutive logs in seconds. Note that the time between the logs column shows time between the current and the next column, and thus, the last time of a particular [Session ID] is NULL.

**AIM**: I want to exclude those cases when the user went offline for a while, but the app was running in the background, so the session ID remains the same. These logs can be identified when two consecutive logs under the same session ID have a large `[Time Between Logs]`. In this case, I am taking the threshold to be 2 minutes (120 seconds). Thus, if `[Time Between Logs]` exceeds 120 seconds, then we should not consider the following rows in that `[Session ID]`.

My final goal is to calculate length of each session of users for a day. This will be made more accurate by accounting for the times when the app is running in the background by removing the subsequent logs.

Thus, the desired result is

| Log Time | Session ID | Time Between Logs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12:00:01 | AAAAAA | 4 |
| 12:00:05 | AAAAAA | 4 |
| 12:00:09 | AAAAAA | 296 |
| 12:06:15 | BBBBBB | 16 |
| 12:06:31 | BBBBBB | 164 |
| 12:11:45 | CCCCCC | 5 |
| 12:11:50 | CCCCCC | 25 |
| 12:12:15 | CCCCCC | NULL |

So far, I have only been able to come up with the following solution -

```
SELECT 
    [Log Time], [Session ID], [Time Between Logs]
FROM 
    LOG_TABLE AS [T1]
WHERE 
    [T1].[Log Time] < (SELECT MIN(T2.[Log Time]) 
                       FROM LOG_TABLE AS [T2]
                       WHERE T2.[Session ID] = T1.[Session ID] 
                         AND T2.[Time Between Logs] > 120)
```

But this doesn't give any records for the case where the `[Session ID]` has no records with

```
T2.[Time Between Logs] > 120
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without diving in too deep to get an ideal solution, using your code just try wrapping the sub query in `ISNULL()` like so:

```
SELECT 
    [Log Time], [Session ID], [Time Between Logs]
FROM 
    LOG_TABLE AS [T1]
WHERE 
    [T1].[Log Time] <= ISNULL((SELECT MIN(T2.[Log Time]) 
                       FROM LOG_TABLE AS [T2]
                       WHERE T2.[Session ID] = T1.[Session ID] 
                         AND T2.[Time Between Logs] > 120), t1.[Log Time])
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed such an obvious solution, thanks a lot!